# Internals of systemtap

Tags: linux, kernel, systemtap

I want to know what actually happens internally when the event written in the tap file occurs and how it is handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the documents presented at the end of the [SystemTap Documentation](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/documentation.html) page, especially the [Locating System Problems Using Dynamic Instrumentation](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/systemtap-ols.pdf) OLS paper, to know a bit more about the internals.

The [Introduction to KProbes](http://lwn.net/Articles/132196/) article at LWN is worth a read too.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore as deeply as you like.  The architecture paper or the stap(1) man page are a good start.  If you want to know everything, "stap -k ..." or "stap -p3 ..." lets you inspect the actual internal outputs of the systemtap script translator: the compiled C version of the script code.